# nothing when i turn key.. silent.. no lights nothing

Tags: starting

i have replaced the starter, alternator, battery, voltage regulator was running great then the next morning I went to turn the key I could not even unlock the doors, close windows, nothing. no sound no power no light. total nothing. dead silence. please help. 2000 infinity i30 please help ty.

Comment: Did you leave the lights on?

Comment: Sounds like the battery is not connected to the car. Either you have a bad connection or the battery is dead  or flat.

Comment: Along with what Krijin Toet mentioned you may want to check for blown fuses/main fuse.